# Reimplementing Enumerable Map method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dictionary

I'm practicing for an internship interview at a ruby shop. One of the job questions I'm expecting is to reimplement an enumerable method.

I'm trying to implement map right now and I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement the case where a block is not given.

```
class Array
    def mapp()
      out = []
      if block_given?
        self.each { |e| out << yield(e) }
      else
        <-- what goes here? -->
      end
   out
   end
 end
```

Using my current implementation. If I run:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].mapp{|each| each+1} #returns => [2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

However, I'm not sure how to get cases where a block isn't passed in:

```
[1,2,3,4].mapp("cat") # should return => ["cat", "cat", "cat", "cat"]
```

If someone could point me in the right direction. I'd really appreciate it. I tried looking through the source code but it seems to do things very differently than what i'm used to.

```
static VALUE
enum_flat_map(VALUE obj)
{
VALUE ary;

RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(obj, 0, 0, enum_size);

ary = rb_ary_new();
rb_block_call(obj, id_each, 0, 0, flat_map_i, ary);

return ary;
}
```

Comment: That's the C source. That isn't going to help you much in reimplementing the method in Ruby. Also, why on earth would `.mapp("cat")` return `["cat", "cat", "cat"]`? That doesn't make sense. The built-in `.map` method throws an exception.

Comment: Furthermore, that is code for flat_map, not map. To be honest, I think it is too early for you to do a job using Ruby.

Comment: maybe you could look at the sources of Rubinius, e.g. https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/bootstrap/array.rb#L77

Comment: Ignore the C code. Chances are, unless you have applied for a very advanced role, the employers just want you to understand `yield`. The no-block implementation would probably score you extra points though!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose that by `[1,2,3,4].mapp("cat")` you mean `[1,2,3,4].mapp{"cat"}`.

That said, map without a block returns an enumerator:

```
 [1,2,3,4].map
 => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:map>
```

That is the same output of `to_enum`

```
[1,2,3,4].to_enum
 => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:each>
```

So in your code, you just want to call to_enum:

```
class Array
    def mapp()
        out = []
        if block_given?
            self.each { |e| out << yield(e) }
        else
            out = to_enum :mapp
        end
        out
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel dumb, but that answers my question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag what is your suggestion?

Comment: Return an enumerator for `mapp` instead of `each`, just like the other answers do.

Comment: That's a +1 from me, then!

Answer (score 1):

```
return to_enum :mapp unless block_given?
```

Should be sufficient.

See the Implementation of map of the Rubinius implementation which is entirely in Ruby:

https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/bootstrap/array19.rb

```
# -*- encoding: us-ascii -*-

class Array
  # Creates a new Array from the return values of passing
  # each element in self to the supplied block.
  def map
    return to_enum :map unless block_given?
    out = Array.new size

    i = @start
    total = i + @total
    tuple = @tuple

    out_tuple = out.tuple

    j = 0
    while i < total
      out_tuple[j] = yield tuple.at(i)
      i += 1
      j += 1
    end

    out
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With [rubinius](http://rubini.us/) there is a ruby implementation written in ruby wherever possible. You can look at their code for *enumerable.#collect*

Interesting is the difference between

- their [ruby 1.9 implementation](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/enumerable19.rb) and
- their [ruby 1.8 implementation](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/enumerable18.rb).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def map!
    return to_enum :map! unless block_given?
    self.each_with_index { |e, index| self[index] = yield(e) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the documentation for [`Object#to_enum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-to_enum)